# When iTunes connect will show in-app purchase earnings?

Tags: itunesconnect

Recently I made a iOS application with **in-app purchase** payment system. App was approved on 28 Jan 2014 and now it has started earning. So my question is simple that if application's feature was bought by some people till 31 Jan 2014, then when it will reflect in my iTunes account?

Receipts saved on my database server are showing total purchase of $41.95 but on **iTunes connect** under `Payments and Financial Reports` it is showing **$0.00** with no **App Sales**.

Thanks
[image]